# What file is creating html?

Tags: layout, overrides, development

I wanted to remove the discount voucher option from my checkout. I copied checkout.xml to the folder I created for my theme overrides. I commented out the section for the discount voucher and it worked, it removed it. However, beforehand I put an exclamation on the label 'Shopping Cart' just to make sure the override was being picked up. The exclamation doesn't show! So, clearly the override is working but I can only think the shopping cart label is being pulled in from somewhere else.

My point is, is there a way to tell what file is creating any piece of html on the page? It would be so handy to point to a heading and for it to give this answer. Just like developer tools do with CSS. All the explanations I've seen so far tell people to look through the list of files to find the one you want etc. With modern tools this just seems a pain and in any case, where you have a situation like mine it would be nice to have the certainty that the code is coming from a particular place as that might be different from the place i would expect it to be coming from.

Would really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's remove the confusion about the `<label>` element. It is not used for frontend display at all, but as human readable identifier for the *layout update* to reference it in `CMS > Widget Instances` in the admin panel.

Then, what you are looking for are template hints. You can turn them on in `System > Configuration > Developer > Debug`, but only on website or store view level, in default scope the configuration is not visible (don't ask why).

The template hints are not that advanced as you might hope, they only show you which parts of the site are rendered by which block and which template is used. There is no information about the XML files.

#### This is how it looks:

[image: Template Hints Screenshot]

#### I can recommend these free extensions:

- https://github.com/aoepeople/Aoe_TemplateHints replace the core template hints with a more usable version and much more information. It works without configuration, you just have to add `?ath=1` to any URL. [Read more.](http://fbrnc.net/blog/2012/10/magento-advanced-template-hints-20)

  [image: Aoe_TemplateHints Screenshot]
- https://github.com/schmengler/TranslationHints adds information about the source of translations. **(Disclaimer: I wrote that one)** [Read more.](http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2015/02/translationhints-0-2-for-magento-published/)

  [image: SSE_TranslationHints Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks so much fschmengler. I though label might be a display attribute as in html forms but clearly not. I will check out those links, really appreciate your help.